# QML QtGraphicalEffects is not Installed

Tags: qt, qml, pyside6

I am trying to build any random QML component, and having this line `import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15` will cause an error: 'module "QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed`

I am running on a virtual machine and just created a new virtual environment with Pyside6 and Python using `pip install PySide6==6.1.2` to get the latest version. I can find the folder GraphicalEffects with a qtgraphicaleffectsplugin.dll in the Qt5Compat folder of the PySide6 Lib so I do not know why it cannot import this module. The other ones like QtQuick.Controls import fine.

I have also used `print("Qt version: " + str(QtCore.qVersion()))` to double check Qt version, and I get `Qt version: 6.1.2`

There seems to be some solutions in other discussion posts, but I have not found one that refers to Python side of things. I am aware Qt 6.0 does not seem to have QtGraphicalEffects, but it's supposed to be in 6.1. I am also not sure if this has to do with the virtual machine because on host I actually have no issue using QtGraphicalEffects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt QtGraphicalEffects is available in PySide6 but the module has changed the way of importing to `import Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` as indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Arch or other Linux distro, just install a package named "qt5-graphicaleffects" (Arch) or "qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects" (Ubuntu)

```
sudo pacman -Syu qt5-graphicaleffects
```

or

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt install qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
```

Hope this help.